# How to count comma separated values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a column in excel which stores single and comma separated values. I want co count the occurrence of each value in the column even when they are in comma separated cell.

E.g

```
Column A
----------
1. 1
2. 2
3. 2
4. 1 
5. 3
6. 1,2,3
7. 1,3
8. 1
```

I want to count number of "1" , "2", "3" in Column A irrespective of the format

When I used the `Countif(A1:A8, "1")` formula, it returned 3 where I was expecting 5 including the "1" in row 6 & 7.

How do I count the values in row 6 & 7 with other values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `SUMPRODUCT` here to add commas before and after the source data, and then look for `,1,` using `SEARCH`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(",1,",","&A1:A8&",")))
```

[image]